Comparativo YTD - Apache Superset
Preciso trazer o YTD do ano atual e comprarar com o YTD anterior, então se o YTD atual é de '2024 - 01-01' até '2024-03-01', eu quero comparar o crescimento percentual com as vendas de '2023 - 01-01' até '2023-03-01'. Mas pelas opções de Time Range que o Superset oferece não consigo configurar isso, ele compara com as vendas totais de 2023. Como posso fazer isso?
Eu tentei trazer pelo custom sql, mas não deu certo. E o pelo Comparison Period Lag ele compara com todo o ano anterior.
